# Scale part of an OBJ in ThreeJS

Tags: typescript, three.js

I have an `.obj` file that looks like this:

[image: Handles]

What I need to be-able to do is scale only a certain part of the handles - in this case the point at which the handles actual bend down from the top. So I'd want to be-able to make them longer in this case.

Does anyone have any direction or an example of how this can be accomplished? All of the examples I have seen are just on scaling the whole model and not just part of it.

I was thinking that I'd need to create a Spline based off of the vertices in the obj and then manipulate the Spline created but I was hoping there'd be any easier option as I don't know how to combine the model with the Spline

Thanks

**EDIT** I believe that the answer doesn't lie with Splines - it in fact lies with morphing the target attributes of the object. I'll post here when I get further on or, if anyone knows what I mean then please point me in the right direction.

**EDIT 2** Following zero's suggestion I'm attempting to use SkinnedMeshes with bones. I'm at the point of trying to fill the `skinIndices` & `skinWeights` with `Vector4` objects but Typescript is throwing an error:

> Argument of type `'Vector4'` is not assignable to parameter of type `number`

I know this is a Typescript problem rather than a ThreeJS problem but I created a jsfiddle that has the same code but the array for `skinIndices` in it is of type `Vector4.` The only reason I can think of that mine isn't is because I'm sending the `BufferedGeometry` of the `.obj` object through the `THREE.fromBufferGeometry` function:

```
let geometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(frontHandle.children[0].geometry);
```

**EDIT 3**

```
let geometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(frontHandle.children[0].geometry);

for ( let i = 0; i < geometry.vertices.length; i ++ ) {
  let vertex = geometry.vertices[ i ];
  let y = (vertex.y + sizing.halfHeight);

  let skinIndex = Math.floor( y / sizing.segmentHeight );
  let skinWeight = ( y % sizing.segmentHeight ) / sizing.segmentHeight;

  let vectorOne = new THREE.Vector4( skinIndex, skinIndex + 1, 0, 0);
  let vectorTwo = new THREE.Vector4( 1 - skinWeight, skinWeight, 0, 0);

  // Here's where the compliant is
  geometry.skinIndices.push(vectorOne);
  geometry.skinWeights.push(vectorTwo);
}
```

**EDIT 4**

I fixed the problem described above and now have this (the blue handle is the skinned mesh with numerous bones inside of it & the vertical blue & green line is the skeleton helper):

[image]

I've also added in the DATGUI helper which looks like this:

[image]

But I still can't seem to scale the mesh just right. The knotted parts of the handle in the screenshot should always stay the same size. I just need the handle part below them to extend when I scale them down and want the knotted parts to scale sideways when the bag gets bigger.

Comment: What about adding bones, weighting the handles to them, and then scaling the bones up/down to your liking ala big head mode?

Comment: i don't know what you mean - can you elaborate or provide a link to an example?

Comment: [Skinned Meshes](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/objects/SkinnedMesh) let you group vertices and instead of transforming vertices individually, you transform the bone.  Each vertex is weighted to the bone and if multiple transforms are applied to multiple bones, the vertex receives both transforms scaled by it's weighting with respect to the bone.  There is a demo in the link.

Comment: thanks - i'll get a look at it now

Comment: @zero298 see my second edit

Comment: Can you post the code that does the assigning?

Comment: @zero298 see my third edit

Comment: @zero298 though your suggestion didn't fix my particular problem I think it could be a possible fix for others - can you summarise your answer and I'll award you the bounty? That is unless someone else comes up with a better suggestion. I'll also post what I had to do in this case to get the effect that I wanted.

Comment: I'm sorry that didn't help.  I went ahead and posted an answer summarizing my comments.  Are you trying to apply translation transforms to your bones or scaling?  The weighting in the knots should probably be zero.  Where is the contextual "root" of the bone for the handles?  What software are you using to manipulate vertices?  It might be clearer to play with bones in the actual editing software that you have like Blender or Maya to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand, you are trying to deform your mesh.  There are 2 principle ways to do mesh deformation:

1. [Morph Targets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morph_target_animation)
2. [Skeletal Animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal_animation)

### Morph Targets

Morph targets allow you to define multiple transform "targets", or keyframes that you can blend your mesh between.  This is usually used to animate a mesh.  Morph targets are verbose.  They are basically a duplication of your mesh, but with each vertex transformed to the way that you want the target to look.  They allow for very fine-grained manipulation of vertices because you are able to dictate the exact transform of each vertex per keyframe.  However, as stated above, they are verbose.  You have to have each morph target available in some fashion so that you can blend the targets together.

If you have a 2000 vertex polygon and 3 morph targets, you'll have to keep the definition of 6000 vertices on hand.

### Mesh Skin and Bones

Another way to control vertex transforms is to use bones.  Bones allow you to add multiple transform influences to a vertex and, in a way, group vertices together so that you can transform the bone to get the mesh deformation that you want, rather than having to manually adjust individual vertices.

You are still going to define transform keyframes, but you are going to define them for the bones instead of the individual vertices.  This has the benefit of conserving space and enabling transform reuse.  Rather than having to define new transforms for every vertex in a mesh, you define a "skin" binding a mesh to a skeleton and the skeletal animation should act appropriately.

---

In your case, I am not sure which would be the more appropriate technique to apply.  I think that a skin would help because you could set the weight of all of the vertices in the handle that you want to transform to the bone and then leave off the weightings of the knots and bag.  Then you could apply whatever transforms you need to make.

three.js has support for Skinned Meshes.  You can see the API and a demo here: [Skinned Meshes](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/objects/SkinnedMesh).