# Alternative for Ribbon in threejs

Tags: three.js

Does anyone have a simple example of a ribbon in threejs.

I've seen these examples [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~lizy/mrdoob-three.js-ef5f05d/examples/webgl_ribbons.html) and [here](http://www.creativewax.co.uk/js/tests/Ribbons.html) but the first makes use of `THREE.Ribbon` which no longer exists and the second seems overly complex when I just want one ribbon built in threejs that looks like these ribbons that I've posted in a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46748323/scale-part-of-an-obj-in-threejs).

I'm in the middle of breaking down the second if no one has any alternative.

Thanks

Note - to be clear I'm not asking anyone to do the work I just want a link or a point in the right direction.

**EDIT**

Ok - so I've made abit of head way with this. I have created a jsfiddle that has the first part of the ribbon that looks like this:

[image]

and here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Katana24/jg1L4kLh/2/) I'm trying to rotate the vector around, what I think should be the y axis, to get the curve out of the ribbon:

[image]

Comment: Maybe extruding curve could help you:  [link](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_extrude_splines.html)

Comment: uhura - nice link. I've never seen that before so I'll investigate it and post back

Comment: not sure, if it helps ) I used `THREE.ExtrudeGeometry()`, instead of `THREE.TubeGeometry()` [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/L0ryjj09/)

Comment: @prisoner849 your fiddle was very close - I'm in the middle of dissecting it for my needs. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: I posted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the ultimate solution, just an idea.

To use `THREE.ExtrudeGeometry()` with `THREE.CatmullRomCurve3()`. The result is not exactly like your desired one, but similar enough.

You can swap values of `hh` and `hw` and see how the result is changing.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 3);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0x181818);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, .3));
var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, .7);
light.position.setScalar(10);
scene.add(light);

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(2, 10));

var ribbonBase = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3([
  new THREE.Vector3(-1, 1, 0),
  new THREE.Vector3(-1, 1.2, 0),
  //new THREE.Vector3(-1, 1, 0.125),
  new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0.5),
  //new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 0.125),
  new THREE.Vector3(1, 1.2, 0),
  new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 0)
]);

var segments = 300;

var hh = 0.0625;
var hw = 0.001;
var profile = new THREE.Shape([
  new THREE.Vector2(-hw, -hh),
  new THREE.Vector2(-hw, hh),
  new THREE.Vector2(hw, hh),
  new THREE.Vector2(hw, -hh),
  new THREE.Vector2(-hw, -hh)
]);

var ribbonGeometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(profile, {
  steps: 200,
  bevelEnabled: false,
  extrudePath: ribbonBase
});

var ribbonMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  color: "white"
});

var ribbon = new THREE.Mesh(ribbonGeometry, ribbonMaterial);
scene.add(ribbon);

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. If you have the time could you explain the meaning behind the profile vertices and how they relate to the mesh as a whole?